# Plot Binary Matrix in Pandas

Tags: python, matrix, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe (data) in pandas that has a datetimeindex (ca. 25.000 days of data) and 527 columns of IDs.

```
                  work_id_10  work_id_100  work_id_1007  work_id_1009
concert_date
1917-01-27             0            0             0             0
1917-01-28             0            0             0             0
1917-01-29             0            0             0             0
1917-01-30             0            0             0             0
1917-01-31             0            0             0             0
```

Each column ID indicates presence or absence of the particular ID with either 0 (absence) or 1 (presence). So, basically what I have is a matrix of binary values.

I now want to create a plot that has all dates on the x-axis and for each column-ID the presences as points.I am using ipython.

```
%matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_yticklabels(data.index)
ax.set_xticklabels(data.columns)
plt.imshow/data, cmap='Greys', interpolation='none')
```

This gives me a MemoryError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 533, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", lin
e 365, in idle_draw
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", lin
e 349, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line
469, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59, in draw_wr
apper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1079, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59, in draw_wr
apper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2092, in d
raw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59, in draw_wr
apper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 367, in draw
    self._draw_unsampled_image(renderer, gc)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 321, in _draw_u
nsampled_image
    self._get_unsampled_image(self._A, extent_in_ic, viewLim_in_ic)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 219, in _get_un
sampled_image
    x = (x * 255).astype(np.uint8)
MemoryError
```

Is this the right approach, and why do I get a MemoryError?

Thank you!

Comment: Without seeing more of your code and a minimal example of your data it's hard to give you something that works.  Assuming you did something like `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` then your `plt.plot(...)` you want to set your y axis tick labels like this `ax.set_yticklabels(something)` where something is your list of column names.

Comment: Thank you, @Scott for pointing me in the right direction. I did not have any other code, but I have tried that and now ran into a MemoryError. I have updated my initial question accordingly. Thanks for looking at it again!

Comment: Divide the problem up more. E.g, comment out the ticklabel lines, does it still break? Do it with a dummy `data` of four-by-four ones and zeros; still broken? Etc. Replace the '/' in the last sample line with a '('. (I strongly recommend working in a script file instead of the interpreter. Others differ, but while you're learning, don't set yourself up for cut-and-paste errors.)

Comment: Are you trying to plot 25000 x 527 matrix?  You might want to break up your data into years so you have 365 x 527 or something along those lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment you may wish to break up your data into more visually digestible chunks.  Here is an example of a random matrix (1s are blue, 0s white) of size 527 x 2500:

[image: large random matrix]

Your data most likely has more structure to it, but may still be difficult to interpret.  The matrix you are describing would be 527 x 25000.  You could display by year (527 x 365) or by decade (527 x 3650ish), or play around and see what works best.

Here is how I would display your data matrix (this is for a much smaller set):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

data = pd.read_csv('concertdata.csv')
print data
```

This prints my fake data:

```
  concert_date  work_id_10  work_id_100  work_id_1007  work_id_1009  \
0   1917-01-27           1            1             0             0   
1   1917-01-28           0            0             1             0   
2   1917-01-29           0            1             1             0   
3   1917-01-30           1            0             0             0   
4   1917-01-31           0            0             0             0   
5   1917-02-01           0            0             1             1   

   work_id_1011  
0             0  
1             0  
2             1  
3             1  
4             1  
5             0
```

Then get the header and the values:

```
id_labels = data.columns[1:]
# take the transpose since you want to see id on y-axis
id_matrix = np.array(data[id_labels].values, dtype=float).T
concert_dates = pd.to_datetime(data['concert_date'])
concert_dates = [d.date() for d in concert_dates]
```

Now plot this using imshow():

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mat = ax.imshow(id_matrix, cmap='GnBu', interpolation='nearest')
plt.yticks(range(id_matrix.shape[0]), id_labels)
plt.xticks(range(id_matrix.shape[1]), concert_dates)
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.xlabel('Concert Dates')

# this places 0 or 1 centered in the individual squares
for x in xrange(id_matrix.shape[0]):
    for y in xrange(id_matrix.shape[1]):
        ax.annotate(str(id_matrix[x, y])[0], xy=(y, x), 
                    horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can play around to make it prettier but this is the general idea.